# How to apply a recursive function to a list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction

With a list of parameters

```
list={a,b,c,d,e}
```

How can I apply a function `f` to obtain

```
f[f[f[f[a,b],c],d],e]
```

For as many parameters there may be in `list`.

Comment: Look up [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold), e.g., `Fold[f, {a, b, c, d, e}]`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Got it, thanks.